# Как организовать навигацию вперед и назад по галерее на jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как реализовать переключение на следующую картинку в галерее в модальном окне? Стрелки поставил, событие поставил, а что дальше делать не совсем понимаю. Задача просто для практики jQuery, из головы.
Спасибо!

https://codepen.io/Slava91/pen/pwBrLP

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#thumbnail li a").click(function() {

    $("#large img").attr({
      "src": $(this).attr("href"),
      "title": $("> img", this).attr("title")
    });

    $("#large h2").html($("> img", this).attr("title"));

    return false;
  });


  $('.close').click(function() {

    $('.modal-window').css('display', 'none');
  })

  $('#large img').click(function() {
    $('.modal-window').css('display', 'block');
    $('.modal-content').attr({
      'src': $(this).attr('src')
    })
  })

  $('.next').click(function() {

  })

});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}

#large {
  width: 600px;
  /* height: 350px; */
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#large img {
  width: 600px;
  /* height: 263px; */
  border: 5px solid #223348;
}

#thumbnail {
  width: 210px;
  height: 256px;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid #223348;
  background: #fff;
}

#thumbnail li {
  float: left;
  width: 79px;
  margin: 8px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#thumbnail a {
  display: block;
  width: 75px;
  height: 56px;
  padding: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#thumbnail a:hover {
  border-color: #405061;
}

.modal-window {
  padding-top: 50px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}

.modal-content {
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

.caption {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
}

.modal-content,
.caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: .6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: .3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #bbb;
}

.paganation {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  right: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="large">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=1" title="" alt="image01.jpg" />
</div>

<ul id="thumbnail">

  <li>
    <a href="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=1"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=1" title="" alt="image01.jpg" /></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=2"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=2" title="" alt="image02.jpg" /></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=3"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=3" title="" alt="image03.jpg" /></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="img/4.jpg"><img src="img/4.jpg" title="" alt="image04.jpg" /></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="img/5.jpg"><img src="img/5.jpg" title="" alt="image05.jpg" /></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="img/6.jpg"><img src="img/6.jpg" title="" alt="image06.jpg" /></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="img/7.jpg"><img src="img/7.jpg" title="" alt="image07.jpg" /></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="img/8.jpg"><img src="img/8.jpg" title="" alt="image08.jpg" /></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="img/9.jpg"><img src="img/9.jpg" title="" alt="image09.jpg" /></a>
  </li>

</ul>

<div class="modal-window">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content">
  <div class="caption"></div>
  <div class="paganation">
    <span class="prev">&#10094;</span>
    <span class="next">&#10095;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку задачу вы себе поставили для обучения, я опишу примерный алгоритм ваших действий:

1. Вам нужно как-то отметить текущую активную картинку. Допустим, вы будете отмечать текущую картинку классом `active`. При клике на картинку в галерее, сначала снимайте со всех картинок класс `active`, а затем текущей картинке в галерее добавляйте класс `active`.
2. При нажатии на элемент с классом `next` ищите в списке картинку с классом `active`
3. Когда такая картинка найдена, ищите следующий сестринский элемент в DOM-дереве с помощью метода [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) и сохраните его в переменную.
4. С помощью метода [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) вызовите событие `click` на запомненном элементе, чтобы сымитировать его активацию и не писать второй раз то же самое, что у вас было уже написано для клика по картинке в галерее.

Чтобы листать в другую сторону, используйте метод [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).

**Внимание!** Чтобы зациклить прокрутку, не забывайте при вызове `.next()` проверять, а существует ли "следующий" элемент. Поскольку текущая картинка может быть последней в списке. Если следующей картинки не существует, вы можете активировать первую картинку в галерее, точно так же с помощью метода [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) вызвав событие `click`.

Для элемента с классом `prev` все то же самое, только в случае уже первой картинки в галерее, вы будете активировать последнюю в списке.